# Why does border-top-right-radius appears on the LEFT side in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, css

I am reworking a web-site to fit IE.

The web site is based on drupal 7 and is in Hebrew.

the rounded ages were compiled using compass

```
/* line 28, ../sass/boxshadow.scss */

#border-radius {
    -moz-border-radius-topright: 8px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 8px;
    border-top-right-radius: 8px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 8px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 8px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 8px;
}
```

Everything works in the modern browsers but on IE the corners are rounded on the left side. When I change the property to left. it works on ie but goes crazy on the other browsers.

[In case you want to see for yourselves](http://www.logtech.co.il)
  The block above was taken from compass.
this is what i am using on the web-site.

```
#block-menu-menu-navigation-tabs li:first-child a,li:first-child{
 -moz-border-radius-topright: 8px;
  -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 8px;
    border-top-left-radius: 8px;
     -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 8px;
      -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 8px;
        border-bottom-left-radius: 8px;
```

}

**using compass

Comment: Which version are using? I also can't find the file: `/sass/boxshadow.css` or an element with the ID `#border-radius`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you want to make it work in IE9 and up. Because lower than IE9, border-radius is not working.

Have you tried to do this:

```
#block-menu-menu-navigation-tabs li:first-child a,li:first-child{
  border-radius : 8px 0 0 8px;/* top-left top-right bottom-right bottom-left*/
  /* no need for browser prefixes */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to target the IE and serve only the changed property.

```
<!--[if IEMobile 7]><html class="iem7"  lang="he" dir="rtl"><![endif]-->
<!--[if lte IE 6]><html class="lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"  lang="he" dir="rtl"><![endif]-->
<!--[if (IE 7)&(!IEMobile)]><html class="lt-ie9 lt-ie8"  lang="he" dir="rtl"><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]><html class="lt-ie9"  lang="he" dir="rtl"><![endif]-->
```

For example you could write something like this:

```
.iem7 {
    border-left:1px
}
```

and so on. You should select the IE Version which does not work.

In case you want to target ALL IEs you can adapt your conditional comments:

```
<!--[if IEMobile 7]><html class="ie iem7"  lang="he" dir="rtl"><![endif]-->
<!--[if lte IE 6]><html class="ie lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"  lang="he" dir="rtl"><![endif]-->
<!--[if (IE 7)&(!IEMobile)]><html class="ie lt-ie9 lt-ie8"  lang="he" dir="rtl"><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]><html class="ie lt-ie9"  lang="he" dir="rtl"><![endif]-->
```

Now you can write css for all IEs:

```
.ie {
    border-left:1px
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I am aware of that. There must be a different approach.